# Can isdigit() return letters in some cases?

Tags: python

For class, I am doing one of those exercises where you have to mentally figure out why a program produces a certain output.

```
 def mystery4(s):
      # sig: str -> str 
      i=1
      acc = ""
      while i < len(s):
            if s[i - 1].isdigit(): 
                 acc += s[i]
            i+=1 
      return acc
```

This code is designed to return characters that complete the if statement condition.

I am confused why calling `mystery4("s45ag2f37gs88")` returns `5af7g8` when
`isdigit()` only returns True for a string that only contains digits.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with computer science, and everything to do with the specific language in which your code is written. Please [edit] the tags to correct it; it will help you get an answer more quickly, as well as help others in the future trying to get an answer to the same question.

Comment: Please tag with programming language. Use a debugger to step through the code to see what is happening. Notice that it's `s[i - 1].isDigit()`, not `s[i].isDigit()`.

Comment: That is new knowledge to me. That’s actually what the class is called. Interesting. It is edited now, the programming language is now there

Comment: Yes I do know it is “i - 1” but what does that change? As I go through, I still don’t understand. It just changes what index it will test for the condition.

Comment: *I am confused why "s45ag2f37gs88" == “5af7g8”* what are you saying here? They are not equal, not does your code return the same string if you input them

Comment: With s[i-1].isdigit() you are checking if the **previous** character is a digit. So you are getting 5, because 4 is a digit, 'a' because 5 is a digit etc. You are also starting at the second character of your input string with "i=1".

Comment: @RaymondChen Provided the correct hint, your solution is the string composed och characters that are **behind** the characters for wich `.isDigit()` returns `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in multiple comments you are checking if character at (i-1)th position is digit but concatenating character at (i)th position. You should note that using this checks only upto second last character so you will also have to modify `if` condition. To fix that you will need to make 2 corrections:

```
 def mystery4(s): 
      i=1
      acc = ""
      while i <= len(s): #<--- Note <=
            if s[i - 1].isdigit(): 
                 acc += s[i - 1]
            i+=1 
      return acc
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, a more pythonic way of approaching this would be with a for loop, avoiding having to access the character positions and potentially mixing them up, and using the characters themselves.:

```
def mystery4(s):
    acc = ""
    for character in s:
        if character.isdigit():
            acc += character
    return acc
```